# Inserting Go's zero time.Time value into a MySQL DATETIME column errors

Tags: mysql, datetime, go

The zero `time.Time` value generated by `Go` throws an error when it is inserted into MySQL `DATETIME` column.

Error that I get: `Error 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00' for column 'expires_at' at row 1`

However, when I increment this `time.Time` value just by 1 nanosecond or change the year to at least 2, it gets inserted without any error.

Does this mean that I cannot insert Go generated zero `time.Time` values into MySQL `DATETIME` column?

I'm using `package sql`'s `Exec` to perform the `INSERT`. I pass the `time.Time` value as argument to `Exec()`.

`sess.Exec(stmt, valueArgs...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because MySQL DATETIME valid range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'. All zero is out of range.

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: Then how come `(time.Time) 0001-01-01 01:00:00 +0000 UTC` goes through?
I'm guessing that 1000 is year thousand and 0001 is year 1?

Comment: I think because all zero is means invalid. And server don't enable `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` then it will show error.
`0001-01-01 01:00:00` is a valid format. But just out of range?


"The server requires that month and day values be valid, and not merely in the range 1 to 12 and 1 to 31, respectively. With strict mode disabled, invalid dates such as '2004-04-31' are converted to '0000-00-00' and a warning is generated. With strict mode enabled, invalid dates generate an error. To permit such dates, enable ALLOW_INVALID_DATES. See Section 5.1.11, “Server SQL Modes”, for more information."

Comment: That same source also says "Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the 'zero' value of the appropriate type (`'0000-00-00'` or `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`)." This sounds to me like inserting Go's zero value should work if strict mode is disabled (with a warning, probably).